# Move Team Foundation Server from one PC to another PC in a workgroup

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, disaster-recovery

I am using TFS 2012. All the PC are connected by using Workgroup.(we are not using domain). The TFS PC is having PC name as PCTFS . We have about 15 developers who use TFS. As we use workgroup so we have created all windows users of 15 developers in the TFS server pc.  So now TFS server PC has windows users like PCTFS\user1 , PCTFS\user2 ,PCTFS\user3 so on.

All these users connect to TFS server PC from their PC. As they have same user created in TFS server PC the authentication works by matching windows user name. So developer can connect to TFS server and work on it. All users have the required permission for all collection databases.

Now we are planning to shift the TFS server to another PC. So PC name having TFS installed will change from PCTFS to PCNEWTFS . So when After restoring the sql databases of all collection and required database the permission will be referring old PC name. So all the users should be again to new PC. Also for all users permission should be given in each collection.

Also if i do add all the users again the added user will be having old OwnerId in tbl_Identity table of each collection as it is restored database. But as i added all the users again with new pc name it will be assigning new OwnerId  i guess. So none of the developers are able to get their old workspaces.

I followed below steps to restore TFS to new PC([referred this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx))

1)I had full backup of TFS_configuration and all other collection database.(backup taken using TFSbackup.exe)

2)In new PC i installed all the softwares(such as TFS 2012, sql server etc).

3)created all the windows user account as in old server.

4)When I checked the New PC it had default collection created which was mapped to SQL server which I stalled.

5)Now I deleted that default collection and restored all databases of my old TFS server(TFS_configuration and all other collection database.)(backup restored using TFSrestore.exe)

6)Now I opened Application-Tier Only wizard and select the sql server instance as mentioned in link. Also changed Team Foundation Server URL properly. I have also cleaned cache.

7)Now when I checked TFS administrative console it had all the collections as my old server.

8) Also i can access group membership etc. But the problem comes as i mentioned above.

So please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [Move Team Foundation Server from one environment to another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx) and [Identities Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253054.aspx)
Be careful of these caveats (from doc above):

- Once a user account is present in TFS, it cannot be removed or have
  another account mapped to it. For example, if you are moving
  DomainA/UserA to DomainB/UserB, the Identities command would only
  work to migrate the user if DomainB/UserB is not already present in
  TFS.
- Because the members of the local Administrators group are
  automatically added to TFS, make sure to remove any accounts that you
  want migrated from that group before you change the domain or
  environment.

Comment: In my case OLDPCNAME/userA exits in the new server.but i want it to be NEWPCNAME/UserA . What i have done is changed only TFS server PC. But in that case i have to change all user accounts to NEWPCNAME/UserA.